# How to fail SSIS component on invalid rows

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ssis, bids

I want to be able to do the following:

- Import a flatfile row by row
- Do a conditional split on a column value of each row
- if i detect a valid value, i want to continue with this row
- if in any case i detect a value that is not possible i want to FAIL the component so the workflow stops and i get an error

Example: I have a file with three columns ( "type", "value", "message")

I want to import that file row by row using the flatfile destination. Then i want to do the conditional split. If the "type" column has "1" as value, i want to write that row into my destinatoin. If the type is "2" or "3" i want to ignore them. However if its "A" or "0" i want to FAIL the component.

I have everything except the "FAIL" part. I configured the output for the last condition ("column is not 1,2 or 3") as "Fail Component", however it does not actually fail the component.

Comment: Do you really want the whole file to fail if you get one bad record? Personally I prefer to send the bad records to an exception table.

Comment: Yes, the whole component, even the whole package should fail - its not my idea, its a requirement ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a script component to the data flow (as destination) and link it to your conditional split for the condition you want to force a package fail.

inside the script component add

```
    bool pbCancel = false;
    this.ComponentMetaData.FireError(100, "Script Component", "Data Error <type message here>", "", 0, out pbCancel);
```

The script component itself will succeed, but the data flow task will fail and should result in a package failure

Comment: Simple, clean, configurable and to the point. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

I just would add something that I searched for a while and finally found alone...

Like Daryl said, if you just use the `ComponentMetaData.FireError()` method, you will see the errors in the execution result but the script component won't fail. The data flow task will fail but only at the end, after doing the job (so maybe after some INSERT and/or UPDATE).
If you want to completely stop the data flow execution, you can do like this :

- Create a **conditional split** on your failure condition with 2 outputs:

  1. Lines OK
  2. Lines that don't meet the condition
- On the 2nd Output, run the script that fire the error with an clear message for each line. The **script component** must be a transformation, not a destination, to have an output.
- After the script component, add an **OLE DB Command** that raise an SQL error on your destination base :
  `RAISERROR(N'At least one line not configured have been found',16,1)`
- Finally, after the OLE DB Command use a **Union All** component to join the 1st output of the conditional split (line OK) with the output of the OLE DB command.

This way, you'll be able to raise an error for each line that doesn't fulfill a condition and stop the data flow task before inserted records if at least one error occurs.